# How to fix the code when console returns null during subscribe method in Angular with MySQL database?

Tags: angular, rest, http, mysql-workbench, crud

When I'm adding a record into the database using Angular, the record successfully added into MySQL database but my console.log returns null during subscribe method. How should I fix this?

here's my order.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Order } from '../order';
import { OrderService } from '../order.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  order: Order = new Order();
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private orderService: OrderService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  save() {
    this.orderService
      .addOrder(this.order).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.order = new Order();
        this.goToList();
      }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();
  }

  goToList() {
    this.router.navigate(['orderlist']);
  }

}
```

and here's the part of my order.service.ts:

```
export class OrderService {
  order: Order[];
  orders: BehaviorSubject<Order[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  private BASE_URL = environment.apiBaseUrl;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public addOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    return this.http.post<Order>(`${this.BASE_URL}/add`, order)
      .pipe(map((order) => {
        this.order.push(order);
        this.orders.next(this.order);

        return order;
      }));
  }
}
```

please help me.. thank you

Comment: **1.** Are you sure the Backend returns a valid response. Try to check the response in the browser dev tools' Network tab. **2.** If the response isn't transformed, `tap` operator without the `return order` would be more elegant here instead of `map` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In service, Please change RxJs Operator from `map` to `tap`

```
public addOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    return this.http.post<Order>(`${this.BASE_URL}/add`, order)
      .pipe(tap((order) => {
        this.order.push(order);
        this.orders.next(this.order);
      }));
  }
```

map operator will transform data. So from the map you need to return a transformed data. if nothing returned you wont receive any value in subscription.

tap operator can be used to work on your data without transforming it.

Also Please check your API response. It is a post method so your payload might be getting saved check if there is any response values.